# Scipy Optimize - missing 2 required positional arguments

Tags: python, optimization

I'm facing this question while trying to minimize pretty straight forward code.

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
from scipy.optimize import minimize

design_var_0 = (0.1, 500, 0.5)

def height_equation(h, D, n, m_batt):
    return return h - D*n*m_batt

def height(design_var):
    return fsolve(height_equation, x0=10000, args=design_var)[0]

def respro_height(design_var):
    return 1/height(design_var)

minimize(respro_height, design_var_0)
```

```
  File "solver.py", line 36, in height
    return fsolve(height_equation, x0=10000, args=design_var)[0]
  File "C:\Users\kj\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 160, in fsolve
    res = _root_hybr(func, x0, args, jac=fprime, **options)
  File "C:\Users\kj\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 226, in _root_hybr
    shape, dtype = _check_func('fsolve', 'func', func, x0, args, n, (n,))
  File "C:\Users\kj\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 24, in _check_func
    res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
TypeError: height_equation() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'n' and 'm_batt'
```

So it seems like the **inner optimization loop** with fsolve is giving me this error.
But if I just call the **respro_height** with a tuple I get the float answer as expected.

```
>>> respro_height(design_var_0)
0.0012771435682421253
```

Could someone shed some light on, why am I getting this error and how to fix it ?

Please note that though, the function **height_equation** refers to an analytical function which has a form of lambert-W and cannot directly be solved for height. That's why I use fsolve to get height

Comment: What is `height_equation`?

Comment: Hi @NielsWouda thanks for having a look at this. height function is a lengthy function referring to some other variables etc. so if i put it here it doesnt do much other than just cluttering the question. but my point is, when i call the function height with 3 element tuple, it works great.  why not when called within minimize ?

Comment: Hi @NielsWouda, thinking about it, I just made a dummy function with 4 variables which works just as height_function and now the code in the questions is self suffient to compile and execute. Thanks again for the interest and giving it a shot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `deisgn_var` argument in `height()` gets passed as an array, not a tuple, when called through `minimize`. I am not familiar enough with the inner workings of minimize to understand why. But the following small modification, explictly converting the argument to a tuple,  should fix it

```
def height(design_var):
    return fsolve(height_equation, x0=10000, args=tuple(design_var))[0]
```

output

```
     fun: 4.363615312479626e-05
 hess_inv: array([[6.05302726e+04, 6.37807548e+01, 5.21903776e+04],
       [6.37807548e+01, 1.06720689e+00, 5.49938958e+01],
       [5.21903776e+04, 5.49938958e+01, 4.50012847e+04]])
      jac: array([-6.05549531e-06, -8.72714736e-08, -6.86066005e-06])
  message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nfev: 64
      nit: 14
     njev: 16
   status: 0
  success: True
        x: array([  7.20604199, 500.00712565,   6.36034335])
```

Comment: you are a life saver. I saw its been passed as a list but never thought its actually the cause. Thanks heaps